# Cannot run an application in titanium

Tags: android, titanium, aptana, titanium-mobile

I am newbie on `Titanium`,

I have installed `Titanium` on my `windows` based laptop.

Also imported `Kitchen Sink` application it in studio.

I have set all the `path` variables also latest `Android SDK`.

Also i have changed Run Configuration log and all.

But when i try to run an application it gives me an error.
I am trying to run it on android `emulator` of `Titanium studio`.

```
Titanium Command-Line Interface, CLI version 3.1.1, Titanium SDK version 3.1.1.GA
Copyright (c) 2012-2013, Appcelerator, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.
[ERROR] :  Unable to detect Android SDK targets.
[ERROR] Application Installer abnormal process termination. Process exit value was 1
```

Comment: try this https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-13429

Comment: or try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/9885555/1688521

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PLease visit this link :- **http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/150991/unable-to-detect-android-sdk-targets-since-ti-studio-31**

Here user is setting basic set up using terminal(Mac)/Command Prompt(Windows).
try using **ti setup** command.

It should be solved.

You can visit this link where problem is discussed :- **https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-13429**