# Android Titanium Issue - Can't run or create new Alloy project

Tags: android, titanium, titanium-alloy

After I upgrade Titanium to 3.1.3, I can't run existing Alloy project.

**When I run existing Alloy project with Emulator, I get an error:**

```
Titanium Command-Line Interface, CLI version 3.1.2, Titanium SDK version 3.1.1.GA 
Copyright (c) 2012-2013, Appcelerator, Inc.  All Rights Reserved. 
[ERROR] Application Installer abnormal process termination. Process exit value was 8
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/eShGA.png

**When I create new project *(File/New/Mobile Project)*, I can't find Alloy.**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/8oe5W.png

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17988399/cannot-run-an-application-in-titanium

Comment: [SOLVED] I have reinstalled NodeJS and now it works fine ^_^

Comment: Add it as an answer then mark it as accept, it might help others

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have installed Alloy, Node JS. If you have installed Alloy, have a look at [Solution for application installer abnormal process termination](http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/140526/solution-application-installer-abnormal-process-termination). It may help you.

Comment: I have installed Alloy and try your link but still not working :(

Answer (score 0):

Check the `/home/{username}/tmp` directory's permissions (755 in linux) or delete it.