# Titanium Application Abnormal process Termination 1

Tags: android, titanium

```
[ERROR] Application Installer abnormal process termination. Process exit value was 1
[ERROR] :  Failed to package application:
```

I am facing this error while running my application. It builds successfully but cannot be installed on the emulator or my android phone.

I have set environment variables as follows:-
Path

```
C:\Users\mumar_000\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\xampp\php;C:\Android\android-sdk-windows;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\bin;%PATH%"C:\Android\TitaniumStudio.exe" &;C:\Program Files\nodejs;
```

JAVA_HOME

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\bin\java.exe;
```

Kindly help me regarding this issue.

Thanks ...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17992524/3419997 may help

Comment: I have already done all these steps but still i am facing the same problem. Kindly help me regarding this issue

Comment: this is the most annoying thing in titanium, another dirty fix could be to install apk via cmd. first `cd your_project_root_directory`, then type `titanium build --platform android --build-only`, after that type `adb install -r build/android/bin/app.apk`

Comment: when i typed "titanium build --platform android --build-only" the terminal gave me lots of errors:-
unable to find jdk
please verify your java_home environment variables

Comment: error: The java_home must point to the jdk but not to the jre
error: You may want to reinstall the jdk from .......

Comment: try running command `java` and `javac` in cmd, if it does not works then java is not added in you environment variables properly.

Comment: All the path errors have been resolved but two other errors have been appeared:- error: Failed to package application error: reset package include C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.4.0.GA\android\titanium.jar not found

Comment: Please help me to solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

There might be one of these solution:

1. Delete the build folder, clean the project and try to reinstall it.
2. On Android devices, I uninstall the same application [if I installed it before], then install the app again. This is the issue with Android devices.
3. Sometimes, when device doesn't have enough memory to install the app, it gives the same error. Try to remove some apps to make space.

Still, if something goes wrong, you have the option to transfer .apk file to your device and install it from there. The thing is, you won't get logs.

Comment: Please have a look on the errors i have mentioned above. And then suggest me what should i do.
I have already done all the three steps you have mentioned above
Thanks

Comment: Okay. In environment variables, the path should be of jdk-bin not jre-bin. What you set is `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\bin`

Try setting jdk-bin path instead of this.

Comment: Also, JAVA_HOME path should be set like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2619584/how-to-set-java-home-on-windows-7

It's not the path to the java.exe file

Comment: After following these steps lots of errors have removed and i am remaining with the following two errors:-

error: Java development kit not found
error: If you already have installed jdk then verify java_home variable is correctly set

Thanks

Comment: can you post your current JAVA_HOME path again please?

Comment: Thanks brother! All the path issues have been resolved but two other errors have been appeared:-

error: Failed to package application

error: reset package include C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.4.0.GA\android\titanium.jar
not found

Comment: sure brother. My current java_home path is: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java;
and that of PATH variable is:-
C:\Users\mumar_000\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\xampp\php;C:\Android\android-sdk-windows;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6;%PATH%"C:\Android\TitaniumStudio.exe" &;C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\Android\android-sdk-windows\tools;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\bin;

Comment: Can you try this once: https://developer.appcelerator.com/question/178926/cant-run-first-ever-app-on-titanium

Comment: Still m facing the same error
My console is:-
[ERROR] Application Installer abnormal process termination. Process exit value was 1
[ERROR] :  Failed to package application:

Comment: Check this: https://developer.appcelerator.com/question/178514/  .. A detailed one. I am not sure what exactly happening in that. Are you using any custom theme?

Comment: Still i am facing the same situation.

Comment: What version of Titanium are you using? in tiapp.xml, is the android target version correct?

Comment: <sdk-version>3.4.0.GA</sdk-version>
and i have installed sdk 1.6

Comment: Titanium studio version is 3.4.1

Comment: I was asking about the Android target version in your tiapp.xml file, like this: `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" android:targetSdkVersion="21"/>`  .. Sometimes it also happens when `minSdkVersion` is set higher than the version used by the Android device.

Comment: One of the issues mentioned above must be the reason for your errors.

Comment: Chek this

 <android xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" android:targetSdkVersion="19" android:maxSdkVersion="21" />/>
    </android>

Comment: My system variables are:-
F:\app\mumar_000\product\11.2.0\client_1\bin;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\xampp\php;C:\Android\android-sdk-windows;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.6.0_07;

Comment: My user variables are:-
C:\Users\mumar_000\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\xampp\php;C:\Android\android-sdk-windows;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6;%PATH%"C:\Android\TitaniumStudio.exe" &;C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\Android\android-sdk-windows\tools;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\bin;

Comment: Change this `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" android:targetSdkVersion="19" android:maxSdkVersion="21" />` line like this: `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" android:targetSdkVersion="19" android:maxSdkVersion="20" />` .. and let me know